# Can I assure that $f=0\,\,\forall\,x\in(0,\infty)$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose $f(x)$ is a derivative $n$-times function in $(0,\infty)$ and exists $x_0\in(0,\infty)$ such that $f^{(n}(x_0)=0\,\,\forall n=0,1,2,...$

The Taylor series of $f$ in $x_0$ is $S_{f}(x)=0$ with radius of convergence $\infty$.

This mean that $f(x)=0\,\,\forall x\in(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not mean that. Not all functions agree with their Taylor series, even though they may be infinitely differentiable. The standard example (modified to fit your domain $(0, \infty)$) is
$$
f(x) = \cases{e^{-1/(x-1)^2} & if $x \neq 1$\\0 & if $x = 1$}
$$
where $f^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for all natural numbers $n$, but the function is non-zero everywhere else.

Functions that *do* agree with their Taylor series are called *analytic*, and that is much stronger than infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

No, the function $f(x)=e^{-1/(x-1000)^2}$ if $x\neq 0$ and zero if $x=1000$ has all its derivatives equal to zero at $x=1000$, so the Taylor series is the zero-series, but the function is not identically zero.

Comment: Just a minor remark: Since he was asking for an example on $(0,\infty)$ you need to add some translations ;-)

Answer (score 1):

NO. For example if $f(1)=0$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/(x-1)^2}$ when $x\ne 1,$ then 
$ 0=f(1)=f'(1)=f''(1)=f'''(1)=... $.

With $f^{(0)}=f$, for each $n\geq 0$ we have $f^{(n)}(x)=p_n((x-1)^{-1})\cdot e^{-(x-1)^2}$ when $x\ne 1,$ where $p_n$ is a polynomial. From this it is easily shown that if $f^{(n)}(1)=0$ then $f^{(n+1)}(0)=\lim_{x\to 1} f^{(n)}(x)/(x-1)=0 $.